# SSH Keys not propagating correctly from instance metadata to authorized_keys: missing keys, user discrepancy, and duplicate key

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, service-accounts

I want to add eight public keys via instance metadata to avoid adding them manually (i.e.: ssh to VMs, pasting the keys to .ssh/authorized_keys, etc.).
I added the keys in Terraform (four distinct keys for two users) using the metadata attribute of the `google_compute_instance`:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "host" {
  count         = var.number_of_hosts
  
  // vm details...

  metadata = {
    "ssh-keys" = <<EOF
    user1:${file("${path.root}/key1.pub")}
    user1:${file("${path.root}/key2.pub")}
    user1:${file("${path.root}/key3.pub")}
    user1:${file("${path.root}/key4.pub")}
    user2:${file("${path.root}/key1.pub")}
    user2:${file("${path.root}/key2.pub")}
    user2:${file("${path.root}/key3.pub")}
    user2:${file("${path.root}/key4.pub")}
    EOF
  }
```

I ran `terraform apply`. I opened the GCP console and clicked on one of the deployed machines. In the "Details" tab, I can see all eight keys in the SSH Keys tab.
Now, when I ssh from my local computer, i.e., `ssh user2@EXTERNAL_IP` (I deliberately started with user2, not user1 - not a typo) and then `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, I can only see the following:

```
user1 : key1
user2 : key4
```

Thus, I can't ssh to VM2 because the public part of the key pair that USER 2 has access to is not `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` even though it is declared in the instance metadata.

On the other hand, when I do `user1@EXTERNAL_IP` and `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, I can see:

```
user1 : key1
user2 : key4
user1 : key1 (duplicate)
```

Since the private key that corresponds to `user1 : key1` is there, I can ssh to VM2 successfully.

What baffles me:

1. Why are not all keys declared in the instance metadata added to the `authorized_keys`?
2. Why is there a difference in the content of the `authorized_keys` depending on the user?
3. Where does the duplicate come from?

---

Edit - some additional information:

1. the image used - `ubuntu-minimal-2004-focal-v20230427`
2. `ssh_config` (only uncommented lines):

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf
Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

3. `sshd_config` (only uncommented lines):

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

---

Edit 2 - relevant fragment of `/var/log/syslog`

@John Hanley

You were on the right track. I can see some messages of the following form: `google_guest_agent[566]: ERROR non_windows_accounts.go:199 Invalid ssh key entry - unrecognized format:` in the `syslog`. However, looking at the form of my keys, I can't entirely agree with a part of your comment: "some public keys have a username appended which will not work". Keys that I read in Terraform and that later appear in the `authorized_keys` look as follows:

```
ssh-rsa AAArsT3 username1
```

or

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2= username1
```

Unfortunately, there is still some wild guessing involved. I can now see four keys in the `authorized_keys` (3x username1, 1x username2). It is better than 2, but I'm asking myself why the four others are still missing. I did a copy-pasting and only changed the user at the end.
Is there an agreement on how the keys passed to the GCP via instance-metadata should look (presence/absence of username, newlines, etc.)?

Comment: My guess is that the public key files are not formatted correctly for Google Cloud metadata. They should have two fields and look like `ssh-rsa B64PUBLICKEY`. Some public keys have a username appended which will not work.

Comment: If we assume that neither `key3` nor `key4` are properly formatted (as neither of them appears in the `authorized_keys`), it still does not explain why the file only contains `user1 : key1` and `user2 : key4`, instead of `user{1,2} : key1` and `user{1,2} : key4`. Since `key1` and `key4` do appear in the file, I presume that their format is valid. The presence of a duplicate in the second case remains a mystery as well.

Comment: Look at the logs the OS creates (not Cloud Logging). You can see the setup from metadata. Show the relevant log entries in your post.

Comment: @JohnHanley I took a look at the `syslog` and edited my post.

Comment: Remove the trailing username and try again. You are getting an error regarding invalid format ...

Comment: The GCP docs is kinda misleading then. Here, in the section "Add SSH keys to instance metadata during VM creation", in the "Terraform" tab (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#during-vm-creation), we can see the following: 
`
  metadata = {
    "ssh-keys" = <<EOT
      dev:ssh-ed25519 key1 dev
      test:ssh-ed25519 key2 test
     EOT
  }
 `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146288/discussion-between-mangata-and-john-hanley).

Comment: There is a difference between updating Compute Engine metadata via the GUI or script and updating `ssh-keys` via Terraform. Use the correct format.